# how to make a discord bot in python that can show a youtube video?

Tags: python, api, youtube

my goal is to make a bot that is able to show youtube videos through screen sharing or camera. Does anyone know how to do it?

I tried to find out how to do it but I have not managed to find something similar on internet, even on stack overflow.

Comment: This is an incredibly wide question. This is a question of the type where you are asking the community to code for you. Either buy a program to do this or get coding and ask very specific questions here.

Comment: I belive discord.py does not support videosharing.

Answer (score 0):

It happens that zoom will share a video in the way that you want.